# which is the correct specifier to use for long when calling stringWithFormat?

Tags: objective-c, ios

I have this code which works well but I don't know if it is the correct way to call stringWithFormat because in the documentation %d is for int and I'm passing a long:

```
    long seconds = (long)[[NSDate date]timeIntervalSince1970];
    NSString *unixTimestamp = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"date=%d", seconds];
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Strings/Articles/formatSpecifiers.html

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try `%ld`:

```
 NSString *unixTimestamp = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"date=%ld", seconds];
```

Abstract from [printf](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/printf.html) docs (NSString's stringWithFormat format follows the same standard as printf function):

> **l (ell)**
>   Specifies that a following d, i, o, u, x, or X conversion
>   specifier applies to a long or unsigned long argument